# Plot artifacts depend on replacement rule

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I am using `Plot` to look at the eigenvalues of a matrix, and find that in some circumstances I get artifacts. For example

```
H = {{x, -g}, {g, -x}};
Eigenvalues[H]
Plot[Eigenvalues[H] /. g -> 1, {x, -4, 4}]
```

gives me

```
{-Sqrt[-g^2 + x^2], Sqrt[-g^2 + x^2]}
```

[image: good plot]

but

```
H = {{x, -1}, {1, -x}};
Eigenvalues[H]
Plot[Eigenvalues[H], {x, -4, 4}]
```

gives me

```
{-Sqrt[-1 + x^2], Sqrt[-1 + x^2]}
```

[image: bad plot]

Fianlly, just to add to the confusion,

```
Plot[{-Sqrt[-1 + x^2], Sqrt[-1 + x^2]}, {x, -4, 4}]
```

gives

[image: good plot 2]

What's going on here? I thought there would be no difference between these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are using `Eigenvalues[H]` inside `Plot` it is evaluated each time for an `x`, and depending on the matrix the order of the eigenvalues may change as well. Evaluate it before and then plot

```
H = {{x, -1}, {1, -x}};
ev = Eigenvalues[H]
Plot[ev, {x, -4, 4}]
```

> $\left\{-\sqrt{x^2-1},\sqrt{x^2-1}\right\}$

[image]

Or you can try to `Sort` it

```
Plot[Sort[Eigenvalues[H]], {x, -4, 4}]
```